# GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1, three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

This has had me beat for a while now. I'm making a game, and the main map is a model using the obj format. I load it like this:

```js
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.setPath('Assets/');

objLoader.load('prison.obj', function(prison){
    prison.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    prison.position.z += 0.1;
    prison.scale.set(15, 15, 15)
    scene.add(prison);
});
```

So when I was loading the same model, but smaller, it worked normally. But, now I have added more to the model, and it is much bigger. WebGL starts giving me this warning: **[.WebGL-0x7fb8de02fe00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1.** This warning happens 256 times before WebGL says **WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.**

[image: Warnings in console]

And with this warning, my model doesn't load completely. In Preview, I see the model as this, **as expected**:

[image: Correct Model]

But in Three.js, I see something different:

[image: Incorrect Model in Three.js]

Well, I'm not exactly sure what's wrong here:

1. Maybe because I'm using OBJLoader CDN
2. Maybe my model size is too large
3. **Maybe I have no idea what I'm doing**

Any help is appreciated, thanks. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Are you sure that obj file is correctly formatted? It sounds like it may be corrupt in someway.

Comment: Has your code changed between loading the model that works, and the one that doesn't? If you've made modifications to the code as well, then you might want to try loading the working model again, just to make sure a problem in a code update isn't causing the problem.

Comment: If your code hasn't changed, it's either a corrupt OBJ, or the model is too big. Rather than making it a monolithic model, you could break it up into smaller models. For example, the cells could be a single model, instanced 4 times, and positioned side-by-side.

Comment: My best guess is that the count for the geometry's attributes don't match up. For example, you might have a count of 150 `position`s, but 200 `uv`s in your attributes. Or maybe your geometry is indexed, and the index points to a vertex count that's too high. Either way, it's a problem with your `.obj` file, because these should always match up. Try doing `console.log(prison.geometry.attributes)` and share what output you get.

Comment: @Marquizzo That doesn't work... When I do `console.log(prison)`, it seems like that prison is a group with 32 children?

Comment: @Anye Looks like you're going to have to dig through those children to find out which one has the out-of-range vertices. :-) I think setting `visibility: false` to each will help you narrow down the culprit, because the error should go away when you're not rendering it.

Comment: Ahh, so it's one of the 32 that's causing the error? I'm trying to repair the obj like @AlexWayne and TheJim01 mentioned

Comment: @Marquizzo What do I do after I find which child was causing the errors? I want it to still be in the scene, just render properly.

Comment: @Anye I just added an answer with details. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is telling you that your geometry attributes count don't match up. For example, your geometry could have:

- 100 vertex positions
- 99 vertex normals
- 99 vertex UVs

... or something of that nature. When looking up info on that 100th vertex, it says `"attempt to access out-of-range vertices"`

Ideally, you'd want to re-export the OBJ asset so you don't have to manually find the geometry that's causing the problem. However, in case you cannot get a new OBJ, you could either:

- prevent the problem geometry from rendering with `mesh.visibility = false`
- Fix the geometry attribute count. To fix it, you'll have to find which attribute is short:

```js
// We assume you already found the mesh with the problem.
const problemGeometry = mesh.geometry;

// Now we dig through the console to see each attribute.
// Look up each attribute.count property to see which one is short. 
console.log(problemGeometry.attributes);

// Then you'll have to set the draw range to the lowest of these counts
// Here I assume the lowest is 99
problemGeometry.setDrawRange(0, 99);
```

Don't forget to also look at the `geometry.index` attribute, if your geometry has it. That should fix your geometry to render with the lowest common number of attributes. See here for info on [setDrawRange](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=bufferge#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.setDrawRange)

Comment: I'll try this, thanks! But a side question, how is this working in Preview then?